# The probability that two or more successive tasks with Weibull distributed lengths have completed?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a set of independent tasks whose lifespan/time it takes to complete seems to fit nicely into a Weibull distribution. The tasks are to be handled one by one, sequentially.

As far as I understand I can use the cumulative distribution function as is to determine the probability that the first task has completed or not, but how would I determine if the second (or n'th) task has completed?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816106/cumulative-distribution-function-of-sum-two-weibull-random-variables
That question points to a paper that discusses distributions of sums of Weibulls.